# Display all list elements that greather than N - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to Display all list elements that larger than N, my code like

```
member2(X, [X|_]).
member2(X, [_|T]) :- member2(X,T), X > T, write(X).
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use `write`? The usual `member` implementation doesn't use `write`. Please update your question with a few examples of how exactly you want the predicate to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you state `member2(X, [X|_])` ? Its not the last element yet. You should only stop when there are no more elements to check: `member2(X,[])`.

And generally:

```
member2(X,[Y|Ys]) :- (X >= Y -> display(Y), nl; true), member2(X,Ys).
```

This way you will display all the `Y`s that are smaller or equal to `X`.

In your code, `T` was a list of elements. You cannot compare it to a single elememt `X`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [include/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3) to perform the filtering. For example:

```
include(<(5),[7,3,2,6,4,5,8],Output).
```

will unify `Output` with `[7,6,8]` (the elements in the second argument that are greater than the number used in the first argument).